# How retrieve user's role with Strapi?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, strapi

I would like to retrieve the role associated to specific user using strapi, but I can't.I tried this query but still not getting the role.

[image: Postman query]

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there is no solution because populate doesn't work for user-permission. But I found an alternative solution in this post :

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/11957

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile, you can simply populate the role for `users-permissions` users.

This both works:

`/api/users/:id?populate=role` and `/api/users/me?populate=role`

You need to grant your user's role the following permission though: Admin panel -> settings -> users & permissions -> Roles -> your user's role -> users-permissions -> role -> find (note: findOne will not work !)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my project.

*The first solution :*
there is actually an endpoint "api/users/me"
you can see more here:
https://forum.strapi.io/t/is-it-possible-to-know-user-role-on-authentication/14221
it will return something like this:

```
"role": {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "type": "string",
    "permissions": [
      "string"
    ],
    "users": [
      "string"
    ],
    "created_by": "string",
    "updated_by": "string"
  }
```

the header of the request has to contain:

```
"Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
```

the final code would look like this:

```
const userData = async() => {
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/users/me', 
headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${JsonWebToken}`,
  })
const res = await response.json()
console.log(res)
```

}

*Second solution*
another solution is using GraphQL

```
Const endPoint = "http://localhost:1337/graphql"
```

you have to install graphql though.

And by letting the token access the me data in setting > role > user-permission >user>me

your will get the response.

my code looks like this
I am using react , graphql-request

```
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request"
const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endPoint, {
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${WebToken}`,
    },
  })
  const query = gql`
    {
      me {
        role {
          name
        }
      }
    }
  `

 const data = await graphQLClient.request(query)
console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
```

the result is

```
{"me":{"role":{"name":"client"}}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when I use endpoint /users/me, I haven't role in response, this is my response :   
`{
    "id": 3,
    "username": "aze",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "provider": "local",
    "confirmed": false,
    "blocked": false,
    "createdAt": "2022-04-06T21:06:36.528Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-04-12T17:57:02.409Z"
}`

Comment: I tried too but i got the same result as as you did. I am sorry, I didn' t check before answering the first methods because i used it before and i worked but not anymore. I m really sorry but i cant help you on users/me because i am not familiar with editing strapi code source. But in the project i am working on right now I use Graphql and It work really well. would you mind trying it? It is used as instructed above. Thanks and really sorry.

Comment: I've tried the work around creating controller withing Strapi but I believe a cleaner solution is using graphql for this.